# SQL Production Database backup during the connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to take a Production SQL Database backup (Full Backup ) while the connection is on and transaction is happening. Does it affect any transactions. Do they maintain any transaction isolation levels ??

Answer (score 2):

Not a development question.

Backups are transactional integer and will contain the transactions closed at the time of backup. ALl new / open transaction during the backup will be in the transaction log and not in the backup.

Database servers are not written by mediocre developers and the specialists know that backups are of paramount integrity. And like usual for high level products they write good documentation which - one can acutally read.

Comment: So if i take a backup, transactions such as any insert,delete,update will not affect the backup. I assume, i get data until any transactions initiated.

Comment: Absolutely. Any transaction will logically not be affected - but just not included in the backup. THat said, obviously, if the transaction doesa a LOT of work, it will compete with the backup in terms of ressources (Disc io, memory) but not in logic.

Comment: Just on curious, i have a question. Is it possible to get Database Backup with a parameter limit. Such as, is it possible to take backup one hour before from now.

Comment: Sure. use a scheduler to schedule the command to make the backup. Or make a backup more often - I pull backups every 10 minutes. Dayily full, every 10 minutes log.

Answer (score 2):

[Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx#id0980008) magazine had a simple explanation for the different backup strategies; for Full Backup it starts out with:

"A full database backup provides a complete copy of the database and provides a single point-in-time to which the database can be restored. Even though it may take many hours for the backup process to run, you can still only restore the backup to a single point (effectively at the end of the backup, but I'll discuss exactly what that point is later in this article). A full backup does not allow recovery to any point in time while the backup was running. This is also the same for differential backups."

Your users will be able to use the application subject to the server having the disk / memory resources to carry on running whilst the backup is processed.